# Using angularjs to get GET and POST result

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, https

If I'm using angularjs and wanted to alter the page based on whether there's a GET request or a POST request, how would i do it?

For example:

```
//index.html

...
<p>{{ message }}</p>
//----------------------------------

// script.js

// create the module and name it myApp
    // also include ngRoute for all our routing needs
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

myApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

myApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

Now, i understand that `home.html` will be rendered when a https request to GET `mysite.com/#/` is fired.

How can i render and fill `home.html` differently if a https POST request is fired for `mysite.com/#/` ?
For example, there is a "Submit" button on the page `mysite.com/#/`.

Thanks,
K

Comment: POST in a SPA is done using AJAX calls not as form POST. Please try to create some samples in Angular to understand the difference.

Comment: By SPA, do you mean a single page application? Why does it matter if it is a single page application or if it has multiple routes?

Comment: And are you saying that if it is not a single page application, we should not do it through AJAX?

Comment: Yes SPA means single page app. SPA does not do page refresh, there is no complete page post backs as required for standard POST. I am saying do POST using AJAX.